# Python forloop only returning last line

Tags: python

Below is my current code. It's supposed to read in a file, compare the regex and see if the input from the text file is a correct IPv4 address or not. It is working correctly, however only returning the output for the last line of the input file. For example, if the input file looks like:

```
 10.0.0.0
 255.255.255.255
 168.192.0.0
```

it will only return that 168.192.0.0 is correct. not any of the other addresses. Thank you.

```
**

import re

filename = input("Please enter the name of the file containing the input IP Addresses: ")
fo = open(filename, "r")


print()
for line in open(filename):
        pattern = '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
m = re.match(pattern, line)
if m is not None:
        print("Match found - valid IP address: ", line, "\n")
else: print("Error - no match - invalid IP address: ",line, "\n")

fo.close
```

Comment: Your indentation is a mess... fix it

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your regex matching within the `for` loop :

```
for line in open(filename):
        pattern = '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
        m = re.match(pattern, line)
        if m is not None:
             print("Match found - valid IP address: ", line, "\n")
        else: print("Error - no match - invalid IP address: ",line, "\n")

fo.close
```

Answer (score 0):

The print and re.match are outside the loop, hence only the last iteration gets printed

```
for line in open(filename):
        pattern = '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
        m = re.match(pattern, line)
        if m is not None:
            print("Match found - valid IP address: ", line, "\n")
        else: print("Error - no match - invalid IP address: ",line, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

going to want to make a few formatting changes, better to open files with `with`.

```
import re
filename = input("Please enter the name of the file containing the input IP Addresses: ")
with open(filename) as fo:
    print()
    pattern = '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
    for line in open(filename):
       if re.search(r"%s"%(pattern), line):
             print("Match found - valid IP address: ", line, "\n")
        else: print("Error - no match - invalid IP address: ",line, "\n")
```